# How to prevent Kubernetes go-client-discovery pkg sending error to stderr

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am using the go discovery client pkg (`k8s.io/client-go/discovery`, `v0.22.2`) to list all supported resources in a cluster ->

```
discoveryClient, err := discovery.NewDiscoveryClientForConfig(GetK8sConfig())
if err != nil {
       // do something
}
resourceList, err := discoveryClient.ServerPreferredResources()
```

When I run this code I get the following error ->

```
I1213 09:19:15.932915   38142 request.go:665] Waited for 1.008601388s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://35.225.61.23/apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s
```

Now, I don't mind the error, what bothers me is that I can't prevent this error from being printed.

Any idea how to stop the discovery client from sending errors to the stderr?

Answer (score 0):

The client use the [klog](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog) library that implement the [default logging conventions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-instrumentation/logging.md). You could read more in the [readme](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog#how-to-use-klog).

You should initialize the library with different values in your main. [As example](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog/blob/main/examples/set_output/usage_set_output.go) :

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "k8s.io/klog/v2"
)

func main() {
    klog.InitFlags(nil)
    flag.Set("logtostderr", "false")
    flag.Set("alsologtostderr", "false")
    flag.Parse()
```

Another approach, if you want to sue Zap logger with json payload as output, you can do something like:

```
import (
...
    "github.com/go-logr/zapr"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/klog/v2"
...
)


func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if logger, err := zap.NewProduction(); err == nil {
        klog.SetLogger(zapr.NewLogger(logger))
    }
```

From:

```
W0630 12:59:05.205701       1 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
```

to

```
{"level":"info","ts":1625058100.1339207,"caller":"v2/klog.go:921","msg":"Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.\n"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the klog reference, I'll search there how to disable the log. 
I still dont understand why they print the error and not return it as the [logging convention](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-instrumentation/logging.md#logging-conventions) requires