# How to output logs in a containerized application?

Tags: go, kubernetes, containers, fluentd

Normally, in docker/k8s, it's recommended that directly ouput the logs to the stdout.
Then we can use `kubectl logs` or `docker logs` to see the logs.
like: `time=123 action=write msg=hello world` , as a tty, it might be `colorized` for human friendliness.

However, if we want to export the logs to a log processing center, like EFK (elasticsearch-fluentd-kibana), we need a `json-format` log file.
like: `{"time"=123,"action"="write","msg"="hello world"}`

### What I want?

Is there a log method that can take into account both `human friendliness` and `json format`?
I'm looking for a way that if I use `docker logs`, then I can get `human-readable logs`, and at the same time, the `log collector` can still get the logs in `json-format`

### Conclusion

Thanks for the answer below. I have got 2 methods:

1. different log format in different env:
   1.1 use text-format in developing: `docker logs` will print colorized and human readable logs.
   1.2 use json-format in production: `EFK` can process json-format well.
2. log collector's format convertion
   2.1 we use text-format, but in log collector like `fluentd` we can define some scripts to translate text-format kv pair to json-format kv pair.

Comment: See if this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335672/2270041

Comment: There are plenty. Google "golang structured logging library".

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has such option of structured logging for its system components.
[Klog library](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog)  allows to use   `--logging-format=json` flag that enables to change the format of logs to JSON output - more information about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-logs/#json-log-format) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/09/04/kubernetes-1-19-introducing-structured-logs/).

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I'm looking for a way that if I use `docker logs`, then I can get human-readable logs, and at the same time, the log collector can still get the logs in `json-format`

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should use text-format in developing and json-format in production. Adding a flag `--logging-format=json` is easy.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that with Flunetd, below are the basic action items that you need to take to finalize this setup

- Configure docker container to log to stdout (you can use any format you like)
- Configure FluentD to tail docker files from `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`
- parse logs with Flunetd and change the format to JSON logs
- output the logs to Elasticsearch.

This article [shows](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/centralize-your-docker-logging-with-fluentd-a2b7e0a379ce) exactly how to do this setup also this [one](https://betterprogramming.pub/centralized-logging-parse-key-value-logs-with-fluentd-9b86140fc5e) explain how to parse Key-Value logs